# How to make sbt publishLocal task compatible with IvyDE?

Tags: eclipse, sbt, publishing, ivyde

I'm using the IvyDE Eclipse plugin to resolve my project's (let's call it A) dependencies. One of those dependencies is another project (call it B) which I build using sbt. The final part of the build is to invoke sbt's publishLocal task to publish the B project's artefacts to the local Ivy repository.

It all works fine up to this point. However, when I then try to resolve the project A dependencies, IvyDE generates an error message saying that it failed to resolve the "doc" and "src" jars. I can force it to work in the end because it doesn't fail to resolve the main jar containing the actual code. Still, I find it somewhat annoying.

After spending a considerable amount of time looking for a solution, I have come up with the following sbt code to change my project B configuration:

```html
import sbt.Build
import sbt.Project
import java.io.File
import sbt.PathExtra
import sbt.SettingKey
import sbt.Artifact
import sbt.Keys.{ artifact, artifactName, artifactPath, packageSrc, packageDoc, crossTarget, projectID, scalaVersion, scalaBinaryVersion, moduleName }
import sbt.ScalaVersion
import sbt.Configurations.{ Compile }
import sbt.Configurations

/**
 * The objective here is to make the artefacts published to the local repository by the publishLocal task
 * compatible with the local resolver used by IvyDE.
 * This is achieved by dropping the classifiers from the "doc" and "source" artefacts, and by adding
 * an extra level directory to their paths to avoid clashing with the "jar" main artefact.
 */
object SbtIvyFix extends Build with PathExtra {
  lazy override val projects = Seq(root)
  lazy val root: Project = Project("xlstocsv", new File(".")) settings (
    artifact in (Compile, packageSrc) := {
      (artifact in (Compile, packageSrc)).value.copy(classifier = None)
    },
    artifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := {
      (artifact in (Compile, packageDoc)).value.copy(classifier = None)
    },
    artifactPath in (Compile, packageSrc) <<= myArtifactPathSetting(artifact in (Compile, packageSrc)),
    artifactPath in (Compile, packageDoc) <<= myArtifactPathSetting(artifact in (Compile, packageDoc)))

  // Lifted from the Sbt source artifactPathSetting() function in Defaults.scala
  def myArtifactPathSetting(art: SettingKey[Artifact]) = (crossTarget, projectID, art, scalaVersion in artifactName, scalaBinaryVersion in artifactName, artifactName) {
    (t, module, a, sv, sbv, toString) =>
      {
        t / a.`type` / toString(ScalaVersion(sv, sbv), module, a)
      }
  }
}
```

This works quite well but feels somewhat over the top. Can someone suggest a simpler way of achieving the same result?